# Merging diffs/hunks

Tags: ediff, smerge

When using ediff, I often get conflicts like this:

```
<<<<<<< variant A
added_function_1 () {
=======
added_function_2 () {
>>>>>>> variant B
<<<<<<< variant A
    body1
=======
    body2
>>>>>>> variant B
}
```

when I expect this:

```
<<<<<<< variant A
added_function_1 () {
    body1...
=======
added_function_2 () {
    body2...
>>>>>>> variant B
}
```

Ediff created two chunks where I expected only one. Is there a way to merge them?

This also happens with `smerge-ediff`, it actually splits up the chunks the diff tool generated.

---

What I actually want is of course

```
<<<<<<< variant A
added_function_1 () {
    body1...
}
=======
added_function_2 () {
    body2...
}
>>>>>>> variant B
```

but I guess that would require semantic diffing.

Comment: When I use your simple example, I get the expected merge. What version of emacs are you using?

Comment: Are you looking for this `+ -combine diff regions` feature?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `M-x smerge-combine-with-next RET`.

Comment: Pretty much, it doesn't work in Ediff though. When I try -- in the C buffer and inside a chunk -- I get "Point not in conflict region".

Comment: @Erik: I don't understand what you mean by "in Ediff" because the sample conflicts you show should never appear within Ediff unless you're "ediffing" different files/versions each (or at least some) of which contains such conflict markers (which is usually a sign of a problem elsewhere such as using Ediff on the wrong files).

Comment: This specific conflicts may not appear in Ediff, I made them up to illustrate the problem. Conflict markers do appear in Ediff's buffer C. Even if this representation of the conflicts never appeared in Ediff, the conflicts themselves could.

Comment: AFAIK Ediff's buffer C contains the ancestor, which shouldn't contain conflict markers either.  Of course, it also all depends on what you mean by "using ediff".  As it stands, your problem description seems too vague to be answerable.

Comment: When there is no ancestor, buffer C contains the result. I don't think my question is that hard to understand for someone familiar with Ediff.

Comment: I'm familiar with Ediff, but I've never seen it put conflict markers in its buffers while active (it may put them when you exit Ediff, I'm not sure, but at this point you're back into the non-Ediff situation where `smerge-combine-with-next` should apply unless maybe the conflict markers aren't using the right syntax).